# pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: Invalid ns

Tags: python, mongodb, insert, pymongo

I try to insert a document into replicated Mongo database:

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient('mongodb://user01:12345678@10.77.14.231,10.77.14.232,10.77.14.233,10.77.14.234/TDB01/?replicaSet=trepl')
>>> db=client.TDB01
>>> ts01 = db.tc01
>>> ts01.insert_one({'a':1})
...
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: Invalid ns [TDB01/.$cmd]
```

but

```
trepl:PRIMARY> use TDB01
switched to db TDB01
trepl:PRIMARY> db.tc01.insert({'name':'Petr'})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

Before the databases was replicated the python code had worked.

I have pymongo (3.0.2) and mongodb 3.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://user01:12345678@10.77.14.231,10.77.14.232,10.77.14.233,10.77.14.234/TDB01')
```